# Ruby assignment methods won't receive a block?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am building a DSL and have this module

```
module EDAApiBuilder
  module Client

    attr_accessor :api_client, :endpoint, :url

    def api_client(api_name)
      @apis ||= {}
      raise ArgumentError.new('API name already exists.') if @apis.has_key?(api_name)
      @api_client = api_name
      @apis[@api_client] = {}
      yield(self) if block_given?
    end

    def fetch_client(api_name)
      @apis[api_name]
    end

    def endpoint(endpoint_name)
      raise ArgumentError.new("Endpoint #{endpoint_name} already exists for #{@api_client} API client.") if fetch_client(@api_client).has_key?(endpoint_name)
      @endpoint = endpoint_name
      @apis[@api_client][@endpoint] = {}
      yield(self) if block_given?
    end

    def url=(endpoint_url) 
      fetch_client(@api_client)[@endpoint]['url'] = endpoint_url
    end

  end
end
```

so that I have tests like

```
  context 'errors' do

    it 'raises an ArgumentError when trying to create an already existent API client' do
      expect {
        obj = MixinTester.new
        obj.api_client('google')
        obj.api_client('google')
      }.to raise_error(ArgumentError,'API name already exists.')
    end

    it 'raises an ArgumentError when trying to create a repeated endpoint for the same API client' do
      expect {
        obj = MixinTester.new
        obj.api_client('google') do |apic|
          apic.endpoint('test1')
          apic.endpoint('test1')
        end
      }.to raise_error(ArgumentError,"Endpoint test1 already exists for google API client.")
    end 

  end
```

I would rather have `#api_client`written as an assignment block

```
def api_client=(api_name)
```

so that I could write

```
obj = MixinTester.new
obj.api_client = 'google' do |apic|   # <=== Notice the difference here
  apic.endpoint('test1')
  apic.endpoint('test1')
end
```

because I think this notation (with assignment) is more meaningful. But then, when I run my tests this way I just get an error saying that the `keyworkd_do` is unexpected in this case.

It seems to me that the definition of an assignment block is syntactic sugar which won't contemplate blocks.

Is this correct? Does anyone have some information about this?

By the way: `MixinTester` is just a class for testing, defined in my `spec/spec_helper.rb` as

```
class MixinTester
  include EDAApiBuilder::Client
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SyntaxError

> It seems to me that the definition of an assignment [method] is syntactic
>   sugar which won't contemplate blocks.

It seems you're right. It looks like no method with `=` can accept a block, even with the normal method call and no syntactic sugar :

```
class MixinTester
  def name=(name,&block)
  end

  def set_name(name, &block)
  end
end

obj = MixinTester.new

obj.set_name('test') do |x|
  puts x
end

obj.name=('test') do |x| # <- syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting end-of-input
  puts x
end
```

## Alternative

#### Hash parameter

An alternative could be written with a Hash :

```
class MixinTester
  def api(params, &block)
    block.call(params)
  end
end

obj = MixinTester.new

obj.api client: 'google' do |apic|
  puts apic
end
#=> {:client=>"google"}
```

You could adjust the method name and hash parameters to taste.

#### Parameter with block

If the block belongs to the method parameter, and not the setter method, the syntax is accepted :

```
def google(&block)
  puts "Instantiate Google API"
  block.call("custom apic object")
end

class MixinTester
  attr_writer :api_client
end

obj = MixinTester.new

obj.api_client = google do |apic|
  puts apic
end

# =>
# Instantiate Google API
# custom apic object
```

It looks weird, but it's pretty close to what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Agreed. I may use the syntax of a method call instead of the assignment. It is just a matter of style for me. In cases like the ones I'll have to deal in this code I think `def assignment_method=(value)` provides more meaning and readability to the code. Besides, I found it really curious this fact. Gonna discuss this soon in my Ruby tech blog. This is the kind of thing that may get someone crazy, 'cause I found no documentation about this.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure how I'd parse your setter with block example. `obj.api_client = 'google'` seems pretty straightforward. But then comes a block. What should it do? When should it be executed? What should be done with its result? What does that have to do with `api_client`, with `apl_client = google`? It doesn't seem very surprising to me that it's not allowed.

Comment: Agreed again. I understand your point, of course. But we can't forget that a setter is also a method and documentation says **all** Ruby methods may receive an optional block parameter. It is also a matter of consistency. This fact is not well documented, I think.

Comment: Should the block belong to `google` or to `api_client=`? I might have another (weird) alternative.

Comment: The block is intended to initialize parameters for the `api_client`. The general idea is creating a DSL to define API clients. `api_client('google')` defines a client for Google API, which will be configured by the block given. Same happens for all API endpoints, where the URL and its parameters are configured inside a block. This way this DSL may provide an easy way to define a complete API client.